# A riddle from the higher mathematics of categories

Tags: riddle, mathematics, algebra

I've recently been studying some topics in higher mathematics ([hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory)), and it inspired me to create this riddle that I hope some of you enjoy.

What's a structure-imposing map from humans to anything else?

Comment: Galen, welcome to the site! Just FYI, puzzles posted here are normally left as challenges for the community to figure out, and not self-answered right away. I guess it's too late now, as even if you delete your answer the high-reputation users will still be able to see it, but something to know for next time :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thanks for the warm welcome. I'll keep your advice in mind for future puzzles. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An anthropomorphism.
>  This plays on the mathematical term "morphism" referring to a mathematical mapping that preserves structure. Since the more general term "anthropomorphism" is more about ascribing human properties, the prompt for the riddle mentions 'imposing' rather than 'preserving'.